# Appending lines to a text file on an FTP server

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, ftp

I am making a simple hangman game as a school project, I thought it would be a good idea if players were able to submit words for other players to attempt to guess. I am required to use Visual Basic 2008 for this project.

I was wondering if there was any way to append a line to an existing text file on an FTP server. And if possible a way to edit existing lines.

For example I want to be able to submit lines in the format of:

Word;Submitter;CorrectGuesses;IncorrectGuesses

And also be able to check if the file contains a line where Word = Word And Submitter = Submitter, so that I can add 1 to either the number of correct or incorrect guesses of the word.

Thank you in advance for any help you can give me.

Comment: Please don't put tag information in your title. The tagging system here is very good at classifying things, and doesn't need help. :-) Please see [Should questions include "tags" in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/172661). Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access).
**This happens if the file not exists yet.**
So, let's create the file if it's not existing:

```
Dim str As String = "string to upload"
Dim vmx As String = ""
Try
    vmx = wc.DownloadString("ftp://your-url/file.txt") & vbNewLine
Catch
    wc.UploadString("ftp://your-url/file.txt", "")
    vmx = ""
End Try
wc.UploadString("ftp://your-url/file.txt", vmx & str)
```

Comment: Thank you, this code is running perfectly. Any ideas on how to edit an existing line in the file based on certain criteria.                                   For example: The player has just correctly guessed the word "Parrot" submitter by user "Jackson" can the program find the line                     Parrot;Jackson;0;0                                                            And edit that to                                                             Parrot;Jackson;1;0                                                          Thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

**Add line to existing File**

Add this to the top:

```
Imports System.Net
```

Connect to the FTP server:

```
Dim wc As New WebClient
wc.Credientals = New NetworkCrediental("FTP-USERNAME", "FTP-PASSWORD")
```

Upload string:

```
Dim str As String = "upload string"
wc.UploadString("ftp://.....com/datei.txt", wc.DownloadString("ftp://.....com/datei.txt" & vbNewLine & str)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I tried the code you provided and substituted in my values for username password and the ftp address. However upon running the code I am given the error "The remote server returned an error: (550) File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access)."